# launch method in Flutter url_launcher dart package is deprecated, but launchURL does not have forceSafariVC parameter

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

"launch" method in Flutter url_launcher dart package is deprecated, and it needs to be replaced to launchURL. But launchURL method does not have forceSafariVC parameter.

How would the migration to this new method look like considering the forceSafariVC parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `LaunchMode`. In general (but not in all cases):

- `forceSafariVC: false` translates to `mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication`.
- `forceSafariVC: true` translates to `mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView`.

If your app has also non-mobile targets (macOS, Windows, Linux, Web), then you might want to use different modes.

If you need to handle universal links, then you might want to use

```dart
    final nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
    );
    if (!nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
      await launchUrl(
        url,
        mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      );
    }
```

See the [official example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher/example/lib/main.dart).

Answer (score 2):

Use [LaunchMode](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher_string/LaunchMode.html) instead.

> replace forceSafariVC and forceWebView with LaunchMode, which makes the API platform-neutral, and standardizes the default behavior between Android and iOS.

See [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/changelog).